# How to store video files in MySQL

Tags: mysql, file, video, mysql-workbench

I am a novice on MySQL and I would like to store video files within it.

I would design a table in my existing database to store them.

The idea is to be able to search and retrieve records as required.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Is it best practise to store large files such as this? I would have thought that performance issues of the database might be affected... am I correct in my assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to store your videos on a disk you control or a cloud service that does that for you like Google Cloud Storage or Amazon S3, and then in your database, store the path/link to that video. I wouldn't recommend storing entire blobs like that inside a database.

Comment: No problem, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can store files in a [blob data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html) that treated data as binary strings (byte strings). They have no character set, and sorting and comparison are based on the numeric values of the bytes in column values.

But it's not a good idea, here are a few reasons why you should avoid store files in the database:

- You need to implement database/application logic to access the file.
- This increases the size of your database and degrades its performance
- Makes backups and data corruption harder to deal with

I will recommend take a look at [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/),

Comment: you can indeed do that, but what's the point though... wouldn't it be much better to store the file somewhere on disk/cloud storage and store a link to that video? What's the use of storing 2GB of "blob" if you can just store it on disk somewhere.

Comment: yep, you absolutely right, but it still possible to store files in myself even if I think it's not a great idea

Comment: ah, you edited your response. Your original response was indeed correct, but the user also asked for "best practise" so that's why I replied here below and was questioning your reply ;)

Comment: Perfect! I did read about using a BLOB data type but I was doubting if this was a good idea or not.

Comment: I decided to add some reason why it's better to avoid store files in the database